# Large Data transfer from one Service to another

Tags: java, microservices, event-sourcing, system-design

In one of my interview, I have been asked a question that how would you efficiently design a system when you need to transfer millions of data sitting in one DB to another service?

What should be the most efficient way to design where we don't compromise scalability and throughput?

Answer (score 1):

I would say it is more to check the way of thinking, then looking for production ready solution.

As a consultant I would start with "it depends". :)

First - more details needed. How big it really is? How often that operation happens? How critical it is? Can someone access the server?

In case of something really big- https://aws.amazon.com/snowmobile/

If that happens once, and there is an access to both severs - maybe simple solution - someone can copy that?

But my assumption is that question is about doing it in Java. Is TCP / TLS good enough it terms o security, data integrity? For me that is OK, but question is to show the way of thinking... Next step is actual processing. It will take a time - how to know that we are in sync? We can use relational DB, that is a bit older solution, but... widely used, well tested. Then started transaction with serialization isolation will do the job. Still question is how to restart whole operation? Besides that long lasting transactions are not perfect for DB. So, if there is a possibility to use queue - I would use it. That is a bit of complication, more resources, but if that operation is crucial, and/or happens often?

Answer (score 0):

There are many factors involved however considering you are talking about movement of data from a DB to a service, we are talking about a service. So here i what i would do :-
Design a async process or a framework by introducing queueing mechanism in place. This framework will have the capability to scale up and down based on the usage. Introduce a integration layer in between the application and the host system from where the data will be transferred. Let it be a AWS SQS / Google PUBSUB or what not. Let you host system stream its data to it and then have your framework pull the data from there and move it to the service asynchronously. Scale your services based on the load etc.